# JSP part of my html code not showing on browser

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

my Jsp:

Below is my JSP and I am trying to get list of my customer and using a foreach tag () and with in the loop(foreach tag) I have list of Action in a drop down button for each row, to be able to edit and delete. The problem is that my code is not showing the Action button that has the drop down in my browser.

The issue is showing when i add the modal tag below. if the modal tag is removed then it works. But i want to be able to add a customer with a modal dialog. How could that be possible. Could someone help. Thanks.

issue Bigin

Edit Customer Detail

issue End

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>">

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="<c:url value="/resources/script/script.js"/>"></script>




    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="navbar-inner">

            <img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/StNavBar.PNG"/>" />

        </div>



        <div class="content">


            <div class="headers">
                <div class="bottom1nav" id="myBottomnav">
                    <h4></h4>

                </div>

                <div class="utilityHeader" id="myUtilityHeader">
                    <h1>Utility Certificate Management</h1>
                    <div class="utilitySubHeader" id="mySubUtility">
                        <h2></h2>

                        <a href="#" class="createCustomer" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#createCustomerModal">Create New Customer</a>

                        <section class="container">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover outer-table table-sort">
                                    <thead >
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No.</th>
                                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                                            <th>Contact Name</th>
                                            <th>Street</th>
                                            <th>State</th>
                                            <th>Zip-Code</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>
                                                <td><a title="Go to the Company Certificate Detail">${customer.customerName}</a></td>
                                                <td>${customer.contactName}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.customerName}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.address.street}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.address.state}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.address.zipCode}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.address.country}</td>
                                                <td>${customer.email}</td>



                                                <!--below line of code till end of tag </td> not showing on browser  -->



                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                                        <button type="button"
                                                            class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                                            data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                            Actions <span class="caret"></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                            <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#editCustomerModal">Edit Customer Detail</a></li>
                                                            <li><a onclick="alert('To be implemented.');">Delete Customer</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                                                                </c:forEach>
                                    <tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </section>










                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


        <!-- All modal dialog goes below this line -->


    <!--create customer modal  -->

        <div id="createCustomerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        Create New Customer
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">



                        <table class="form-table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="pool-name">Customer Name:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="name" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Contact Name:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="actName" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="description">Street:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="street" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Zip-Code:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="zip" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Country:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="country" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Email:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="email" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer" value="Create"
                                class="btn btn-default" onClick="alert('To be Implemented');" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <!--Edit Customer Modal  --> 

        <div id="editCustomerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        Create New Customer
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">



                        <table class="form-table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="pool-name">Customer Name:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="name" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Contact Name:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="contact" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="description">Street:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="street" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Zip-Code:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="zip" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Country:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="country" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                        class="not-required" for="expire-after">Email:</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="email" path="#"
                                        class="form-control" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer" value="Save"
                                class="btn btn-default" onClick="alert('To be Implemented');" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test you code with below change,It Working fine.

```
  <c:forEach var="customer" begin="1" end="5">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>
                                            <td><a title="Go to the Company Certificate Detail">1</a></td>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                            <td>5</td>
                                            <td>6</td>
                                            <td>7</td>
                                            <td>8</td>



                                            <!--below line of code till end of tag </td> not showing on browser  -->



                                            <td>
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                        Actions <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                        <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#editCustomerModal">Edit Customer Detail</a></li>
                                                        <li><a onclick="alert('To be implemented.');">Delete Customer</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                                                            </c:forEach>
```

Please check that is there any error in browser console?

Comment: The problem was with my JavaScript function after that got solved the issue got resolved